# node.js (socket.io chat) ram usage goes up and stop working

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io, chat

I have a little problem with my socket.io chat app. When I'm starting it, it uses 1% RAM and when it runs 2 days, it goes up to 10%+ and stop working and I have to restart it again and again.... Here is my code, how can I fix it?
Thanks for the answers!

```
var https = require('https');
var fs = require('fs');
var mysql = require('mysql');


var mysqlInfo;
mysqlInfo = {
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'user',
  password : 'pass',
  database : 'user',
  charset  : 'utf8_general_ci'
};

var mysqlConnection = mysql.createConnection(mysqlInfo);


var options = {
    key:    fs.readFileSync('ssl/server.key'),
    cert:   fs.readFileSync('ssl/server.crt'),
    ca:     fs.readFileSync('ssl/ca.crt')
};
var app = https.createServer(options);
io = require('socket.io').listen(app);
app.listen(3000);

var login_users = {};

var channels = ['english'];


io.on('connection', function(socket){
        setTimeout(function(){
                socket.emit('login', '');
        }, 1000);
        socket.join('english');
        socket.channel='english';
        socket.on('login', function(login){
                var login_json = JSON.parse(login);
                mysqlConnection.query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE id=? and token=?", [login_json.id,login_json.token], function(err, results) {
                        if(results.length==1){
                                login_users[socket.id] = socket;
                                login_users[socket.id]["id"] = login_json.id;
                                login_users[socket.id]["token"] = login_json.token;
                                socket.join(login_json.id);
                        }
                });
        });
        socket.on('chat', function(message){
                if(typeof socket.id !== 'undefined'){
                        mysqlConnection.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=? and token=?", [socket.id,socket.token], function(err, results) {
                                        io.in(socket.channel).emit('chat', '{"message":"'+message+'"}');
                                }
                        });
                }
        });
        socket.on('channel_change', function(channel){
                if (channels.indexOf(channel) > -1 && socket.channel!=channel) {
                        socket.leave(socket.channel);
                        socket.join(channel);
                        socket.channel=channel;
                }
        });
});

setInterval(function () {
        mysqlConnection.query('SELECT 1');
}, 5000);
```

Comment: you keep your connection object alive the entire time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to close your mysql connections after you use them.
Basically whats happening is that you keep making these queries and keep the connections object open. Chances are the connections periodically drops but your node script is still maintaining resources to keep the connections open and creating a new connection for the subsequent connections. This is where the memory leak is comming from. You should always create a new connections for each query and close it when you get the results.

```
var https = require('https');
var fs = require('fs');
var mysql = require('mysql');


var mysqlInfo;
mysqlInfo = {
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'user',
  password : 'pass',
  database : 'user',
  charset  : 'utf8_general_ci'
};




var options = {
    key:    fs.readFileSync('ssl/server.key'),
    cert:   fs.readFileSync('ssl/server.crt'),
    ca:     fs.readFileSync('ssl/ca.crt')
};
var app = https.createServer(options);
io = require('socket.io').listen(app);
app.listen(3000);

var login_users = {};

var channels = ['english'];


io.on('connection', function(socket){
    setTimeout(function(){
            socket.emit('login', '');
    }, 1000);
    socket.join('english');
    socket.channel='english';
    socket.on('login', function(login){
        var login_json = JSON.parse(login);
        var mysqlConnection = mysql.createConnection(mysqlInfo);
        mysqlConnection.query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE id=? and token=?", [login_json.id,login_json.token], function(err, results) {
            if(results.length==1){
                    login_users[socket.id] = socket;
                    login_users[socket.id]["id"] = login_json.id;
                    login_users[socket.id]["token"] = login_json.token;
                    socket.join(login_json.id);
            }
            mysqlConnection.end()
        });
    });
    socket.on('chat', function(message){
        if(typeof socket.id !== 'undefined'){
            var mysqlConnection = mysql.createConnection(mysqlInfo);
            mysqlConnection.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=? and token=?", [socket.id,socket.token], 
              function(err, results) {
                  mysqlConnection.end();
                  io.in(socket.channel).emit('chat', '{"message":"'+message+'"}');
              }
            });
        }
    });
    socket.on('channel_change', function(channel){
        if (channels.indexOf(channel) > -1 && socket.channel!=channel) {
                socket.leave(socket.channel);
                socket.join(channel);
                socket.channel=channel;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I created an error handler now, and I get this error: "TypeError: undefined is not a function" How can I fix it?

Comment: oh my bad, its not close() its end(), I updated the code sample.
it would help you to look at the docs on releasing connections https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql

Comment: Okay, I still have a problem with it. When I started it, it uses 0.5% RAM and know(after 2 hours) its uses 4%. It goes up slowly.. Why? How can I fix it?

Comment: do you still have that
    
    setInterval(function () {
        mysqlConnection.query('SELECT 1');
    }, 5000);

snippit of code at the end?

Comment: Just a suggestion, "SELECT * " is always considered an evil practice. For instance today you could have only 4 columns in the table. Tomorrow someone decides to add a blob column that contains the image (picture) of the user, with addres, phone, etc and all of a sudden you have 20 fields with loads of data per row. And now you are retrieving ALL of those fields in the same query, when you originally had the need for just the original 4 columns.